# Memory continually being eaten up since I had SQL Server 2014 SSMS installed

Tags: sql-server-2014, memory

I know SQL Server will take up all memory on a server by design, but this is my desktop not a network server.  What should I be looking at in terms of what they installed that needs to be changed so that I can work again?

I am running both SQL Server 2014 and SQl server 2008 SSMS as well as SSIS packages for both. I have no SSMS open and no are there programs besides this and task Manager Lync and my system is up to 94% of my memory being used just after a reboot. I never had this issue before they loaded 2014. But it has been continual since they did. I am sure there is some setting I need to change, but can't find anything on it as all the things I find seem to refer to how memory is handled on a server. It currently is running SQLServer.exe even though I have not opened SSMS since the reboot.

I have 6 GB of memory on an Intel Xeon CPU and Windows 7. It is an HP Z600 workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is set to start by default on system start. SSMS is just your management studio and not the SQL Server engine itself. 
You can set SQL Server service (services.msc) to manual, and set the maximum memory it can allocate lower if that is a concern to you.

Important: 
SSMS <> SQLServer.exe

Comment: I pointed out that I had not opened SSMS because I had done nothing that should have made sqlserver.exe start which is the service running on my computer. Why would my desktop be starting sqlserver.exe? And how do I set the service to manual?

Comment: To add, all the databases I use are on a server. I do not run any personal databases on my desktop;

Comment: As I said, sqlserver.exe will start automatically, it is not "triggered" by opening SSMS. If a SQL Server Instance is installed, you'll see the sqlserver.exe service running, which, starts automatically. Check your services.msc under SQLServer, and you'll see the instance is running. SQL will run regardless of where the databases are, the service is installed and running on your desktop.

Comment: So what do I do to keep it from eating up all my memory so that I can't work?

Comment: As the answer states, sqlservr.exe is a service, set to run when your machine starts up by default. It sounds like someone installed SQL 2014 as a full server instance, instead of just installing the tools. sqlservr.exe does not need to be running for you to run SSMS. If you have sufficient rights, (again, as stated in the answer) go to Services, change its Startup Type from "Automatic" to "Manual", and stop the service. If you don't have sufficient rights on your machine, contact someone who can make these changes (I'd talk to whoever installed the software).

Comment: "Services" can be found under "Administrative Tools". Depending on your OS version, that will either be available as an item of its own, or under "Control Panel"

Comment: Start->Run->services.msc. Alternatively open SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Apparently everything was set to automatic.   I do think they installed it as a full server instead of just the tools.  Can I set SQL Server Browser to manual?

Comment: You can set all to manual. Since this is not intended for server type DB hosting, you shouldn't have issues. Correct action would be to have the instance uninstalled, unless it's a dev copy, you could potentially be incurring/using a license.